# How to fix: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint

Tags: c#, sql-update

Im makeing a update statement from my C# code. Now I had it working but I needed to add a constructor to my class. now that I added the constructor it doesn't work anymore.

If i dont make a constructur it does work

class

```
namespace FontysHotel
{
    public class Medewerker
    {
        //instantie variabelen
        private int id;
        private string naam;
        private string functie;
        private DateTime datum_in_dienst;
        private string telefoonnummer;
        private string email;
        private string wachtwoord;
        private int hotelid;
        private int managementid;

        //proporties
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; } set { id = value; }
        }
        public string Naam
        {
            get { return naam; } set { naam = value; }
        }
        public string Functie
        {
            get { return functie; } set { functie = value; }
        }
       public DateTime Datum_in_dienst
        {
            get { return datum_in_dienst; } set { datum_in_dienst = value; }
        }
        public string Telefoonnummer
        {
            get { return telefoonnummer; } set { telefoonnummer = value; }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; } set { email = value; }
        }
        public string Wachtwoord
        {
            get { return wachtwoord; } set { wachtwoord = value; }
        } 
        public int Hotelid
        {
            get { return hotelid; } set { hotelid = value; }
        }
        public int Managementid
        {
            get { return managementid; } set { managementid = value; }
        }
        //constructor
        public Medewerker(int id, string naam, string functie, DateTime datum_in_dienst, string telefoonnummer, string email, string wachtwoord, int hotelid, int mangementid)
        {
            Id = id;
            Naam = naam;
            Functie = functie;
            Datum_in_dienst = datum_in_dienst;
            Telefoonnummer = telefoonnummer;
            Email = email;
            Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
            Hotelid = hotelid;
            Managementid = managementid;
        }


    }
}
```

method

```
 public static void UpdateSchoonmaker(int id, string naam, string functie, DateTime datum_in_dienst, string telefoonnummer, string email,string wachtwoord, string hotelid, string managementid )
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update medewerker set medewerkerid = " + id + ", naam ='" + naam + "',functie ='" + functie + "',datum_in_dienst = '" + datum_in_dienst + "',telefoonnummer =" + telefoonnummer + ",email ='" + email + "', wachtwoord ='" +wachtwoord+ "',hotelid = "+hotelid+", managementid ="+managementid+" where medewerkerid =" + id, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
```

constructor involved at getallstaf

```
public static List<Medewerker> Getmedewerker()
        {
            var result = new List<Medewerker>();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                const string query = "Select * from medewerker where functie = 'schoonmaak'";
                SqlCommand selectMedewerker = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = selectMedewerker.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Medewerker mdw = new Medewerker((int)reader["medewerkerid"], (string)reader["naam"], (string)reader["functie"], (DateTime)reader["datum_in_dienst"], (string)reader["telefoonnummer"], (string)reader["email"], (string)reader["wachtwoord"], (int)reader["hotelid"], (int)reader["managementid"]);
                    //mdw.Id = (int)reader["medewerkerid"];
                    //mdw.Naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                    //mdw.Functie = (string)reader["functie"];
                    //mdw.Datum_in_dienst = (DateTime)reader["datum_in_dienst"];
                    //mdw.Telefoonnummer = (string)reader["telefoonnummer"];
                    //mdw.Email = (string)reader["email"];
                    //mdw.Wachtwoord = (string)reader["wachtwoord"];
                    //mdw.Hotelid = (int)reader["hotelid"];
                    //mdw.Managementid = (int)reader["managementid"];
                    result.Add(mdw);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

code that gets info from datagrid

```
 private void DgSchoonmedewerker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
            var row_selected = dg.SelectedItem as Medewerker;
            if (row_selected != null)
            {
                medewerkerid = row_selected.Id;
                tbNaamSchoon.Text = row_selected.Naam;
                tbTelefoonSchoon.Text = row_selected.Telefoonnummer;
                tbEmailSchoon.Text = row_selected.Email;
                tbWachtSchoon.Text = row_selected.Wachtwoord;
                cbHotelSchoonmaak.Text = row_selected.Hotelid.ToString();
                cbManagerSchoonmaak.Text = row_selected.Managementid.ToString();
                dpDatumindienst.SelectedDate = row_selected.Datum_in_dienst;
            }
        }
```

now this way if I click anything in the datagrid it fills the information to the textboxes. The next code is how i send the code to the Update method

```
 Database.UpdateSchoonmaker(medewerkerid, tbNaamSchoon.Text, "Schoonmaak",Convert.ToDateTime(dpDatumindienst.SelectedDate), tbTelefoonSchoon.Text, tbEmailSchoon.Text, tbWachtSchoon.Text, cbHotelSchoonmaak.Text, cbManagerSchoonmaak.Text);
```

So First I use the public static list getmedewerker to load the information. Here is probaly something wrong loading in the managersids. because as you can see in the first screenshot they are all set to 0 while in sql server express they do have a value.
Now if I click something in the datagrid the combox for managersid's also doesnt automaticly fill and if I manaul select a managersid it then adds 0 to the managersid.
if I dont put anything in the new medewerker and uncomment the mdw.XXX = and comment the constructor the update does work

I expect it to update a row in the table. But how do I add constructor to the class and make the update statement so that I dont get this error message

edit
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be using ExecuteNonQuery for an UPDATE statement

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to write a value in a column which can't accept that value because of a foreign key constraint.  (The value doesn't exist in the referenced table.)  Which column is it?  What is the value you're trying to write?  What value were you expecting?  Why?

Comment: Also... How do you think that constructor is even involved at all?  You're not using that constructor here.  Or even that class.  It's entirely unrelated.

Comment: Im trying to set the staff's id and it needs to keep the same value, but if i remove the constructor it works.

Comment: @Jdiehl: Stop focusing on the constructor.  The method executing the `UPDATE` statement doesn't even use the constructor.  When you debug your code, what are the exact values being used in your `UPDATE` query?  Are they what you expect?  Also, note that this code is wide open to SQL injection.  Now would be a good time to start using parameterized queries.

Comment: if i use the debugger it doesnt read the managersid's

Comment: @Jdiehl: You're going to need to be more specific.  We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: @David the first screen are the managersid's in the application. the 2nd screen is the sql server express where all the staff members are.

Comment: @Jdiehl: How is the first screenshot related to the code?  What is it a screenshot of?  Where are you calling `UpdateSchoonmaker()` and what values are you passing to it?  Where do those values come from?  The error hasn't changed... You're trying to use a value that isn't in the related table.  Focus on that value and where it's coming from.  You seem to be missing some steps between reading data and writing data, and in those steps you have some false assumptions about that data.

Comment: @david hope i made it more clear now

Comment: I just spotted that you're setting the 'managementid' field in your update query. If it's supposed to be a primary key then you shouldn't be setting that in your update query. Also, it's an update query, no data should be returned, hence you should be using .ExecuteNonQuery() instead of .ExecuteReader(). I've edited my answer if you want to give it another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing some research into object orientated programming. I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty close to what I'm guessing you want.

```
public class Medewerker
{
    //instantie variabelen
    public int id {get;}
    public string naam {get; set;}
    public string functie {get; set;}
    public DateTime datum_in_dienst {get; set;}
    public string telefoonnummer {get; set;}
    public string email {get; set;}
    public string wachtwoord {get; set;}
    public int hotelid {get; set;}
    public int managementid {get; set;}

    //constructor
    public Medewerker(int id, string naam, string functie, DateTime datum_in_dienst, string telefoonnummer, string email, string wachtwoord, int hotelid, int mangementid)
    {
        Id = id;
        Naam = naam;
        Functie = functie;
        Datum_in_dienst = datum_in_dienst;
        Telefoonnummer = telefoonnummer;
        Email = email;
        Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
        Hotelid = hotelid;
        Managementid = managementid;
    }

    public static void UpdateSchoonmaker()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update medewerker set naam ='" + this.naam + "',functie ='" + this.functie + "',datum_in_dienst = '" + this.datum_in_dienst + "',telefoonnummer =" + this.telefoonnummer + ",email ='" + this.email + "', wachtwoord ='" +this.wachtwoord+ "',hotelid = "+this.hotelid+", managementid ="+this.managementid+" where medewerkerid =" + id, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in whatever area you want to call the method

```
var myMedewerker = new Medewerker(0, "Matt", ...);
myMedewerker.naam = "James";
myMedewerker.UpdateSchoonmaker();
```

Comment: executenonquery() returns following error ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' FontysHotel D:\semester 2\Pred\Pred solution\FontysHotel\FontysHotel\Database.cs 304 Active
```

Comment: `reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - ExecuteNonQuery does not return a DataReader, it [returns an int value showing how many rows were affected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Sorry yeah, was just mostly copying code, will edit now.

Comment: @stuartd Good spot, thanks for that. Hopefully should be good now.